# Adobe I - PNG export is not transparent and cannot be viewed in Photo Viewer

Tags: adobe-illustrator, transparency, png, black

When I export my image as a PNG file it does not come out as so.

When I view it in windows photo viewer the image is just black. If I import it to Paint the image comes up but it has a normal white background around it.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Look below for how you're saving and make sure you have transparency selected or checked.

**File -> Export**

Make sure Background Color is set to Transparent.

[image: file export]

**File -> Save For Web...**

Make sure the Transparency box is checked.

[image: transparency setting save for web]